# Compensating for latency (MORE THAN NETWORK LAG)

Tags: networking, input, controller, latency, lag

First, this is a question not only about network lag, but delay from wireless controllers and delay to TVs/Monitors. For a fast-paced action game, how do you compensate for these things? Has anyone come up with a reusable way to do this? If so, I haven't seen one. I'd like to see a game framework that includes this out of the box.

If there is no previous examples available, how would one implement this into an Update(float deltaTime) loop? Would it be possible to disguise or hide lag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with Latency in Networked Games](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515/dealing-with-latency-in-networked-games)

Answer (score 0):

[Dead Reckoning: Latency Hiding for Networked Games](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3230/dead_reckoning_latency_hiding_for_.php)

[Valve Developer Communnity: Source Multiplayer Networking](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking)

Ah!, it has been asked previously: [Dealing with Latency in Networked Games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515/dealing-with-latency-in-networked-games)

Voting to close.

Comment: I'm more interested in delay to tvs and controllers. Network latency has already been covered numerous times, I was just curious to see if it could be combined with the other lagging inputs/outputs in order to make game development simpler.

Comment: why would there be any appreciable delay from wireless controller? Network lag will be orders of magnitude higher.

Comment: I can't play guitar hero on my high-def tv screen. it has to deal with wireless controller lag + tv update lag

Comment: so, your question is really "Why can't I play guitar hero on my high-def tv" ?

Comment: That's an example of wireless controller lag and tv update lag. I want to know if there's any articles on combating this lag, or if there's a system already in place.