# Server-Client Syncing

Tags: c#, networking, synchronization, real-time, game-development

I've been looking up on google for this answer, and I just can't find the answer to my question.  I have a 2D rpg that I want to build a client-server architecture with.  How do I 'sync' things?  cause with lag, things are all 'back in time' by the time data reaches the other end.  Even with client side interpolation etc, how do I get a 'common time' between clients and the server?  Ie, if it took 60ms to go from client->server, -how- does the server know it was 60ms, or 90, 120, etc?  The only way would be to have a common time between them somehow, for I could use lag calculations to better sync things?  I'm totally lost on his :(

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515/dealing-with-latency-in-networked-games) question. Since it's not a first person shooter you won't need to send as much information so it should be easier to add in techniques such as prediction and interpolation.

Take a look at the [Steam wiki article](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) mentioned in the answer, it's a good starting point.