# How to create smooth animation with NodeJS, Socket.io game server

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, animation, socket.io

I've made HTML5 games before and have done smooth animations using this feature of HTML5 `animate(highResTimestamp)` It works really well and creates smooth animations.

However, I've only made local games. I am working on making an online game server and using nodejs. I was following a tutorial and instead of using `animate(highResTimestamp)` took keep track of the frame rate they made nodejs send a signal to the client every so often to update the position of each character. As seen below,

```
setInterval(function() {
    var pack = [];
    for(var i in SOCKET_LIST) {
        var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
        pack.push({
          x:socket.x,
          y:socket.y
        });
    }

    for(var i in SOCKET_LIST) {
        var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
        socket.emit('newPositions', pack);
    }
}, 1000/25);
```

I've added a simple method that detects a keyboard keydown and will send a signal to the server saying to increase x or y. Then the client is listening for the message `newPositions` and when it recieves it, it clears the canvas and draws all the characters in their new posisitons.

This works, however, it is not smooth, it is very edgy feeling. Is there a way around this? Is there a better way to make a nodejs game server? Should the server be controlling the frame rate or should I be using `animate(highResTimestamp)` to control the frame rate?

Comment: It feels like this question is probably far too broad for stack overflow - requiring a long treatise on game development to really answer.  No interaction between client and server is going to run at typical animation frame rates, particular as your server starts to serve many users or is situated far from the user.  So, animation needs to be run from the client with the server providing updates caused by other players as often as practical and the client adapting as it gets new data.  Designing "near real-time multi-player games" that work well under load and with imperfect networks is hard.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515/dealing-with-latency-in-networked-games